# Filtering CSV records in d3.js enter/update based on user input

Tags: d3.js

I am comfortable with d3 but only starting to understand transitions/animations.
I am trying to take [M Bostock's Marey chart for trains](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5544008) as a base and produce an interactive chart for Mumbai Western Railway system. [The bl.ocks page is here](http://bl.ocks.org/ratnakarv/6715343). I have made slight changes so far as to adding tip text for lines, colour coding the station name as per zone etc.

Mumbai Western train system has fast and slow trains. The requirement is that, based on User input, the chart either displays all trains or Fast only. Fast trains are in black.
The column 'type' in csv either dictates a train is fast (F) or slow(S).

I am not able to think of best way to accomodate the transition framework. I have thought of the following as options so far.

1. Having two seperate csv files(one for all and other for fast only). Having a 'on click' listener outside d3.csv function and calling the appropriate d3.csv loader when selected. This is probably crude and not so elegant
2. There is already a filter here selecting only SF trains. but how do i incorporate only S or both SF depending on on click listener.

   ```
   var train = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "train")
     .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
   .selectAll("g")
     .data(trains.filter(function(d) { return /[SF]/.test(d.type); }))
    //.data(trains)
   .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", function(d) { return d.type; });
   ```

Appreciate if some one can help with an appropriate and elegant way to incorporate this transition

Edit: I know that for now, I have included form radio buttons outside SVG container which is puching the bottom X axis out of SVG container. Once the transitions part is covered I will attend to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you already have looks like a good start to me. The basic pattern is this.

- Render a default selection when the CSV is loaded.
- When the selection changes, filter the data to display like you already do. You might want to keep a reference to the currently selected data somewhere. Remember that your filter function can be something arbitrarily complex, i.e. you can check all the conditions you like.
- Select all the train paths and pass in the new data. You will need to provide a key function (second argument to `.data()`, see [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data)) to make sure that data and lines are matched correctly.
- Handle the enter/update/exit selections. Start without transitions first and then add them.

How exactly you want to do the transitions depends on you, but you could have for example enter and exit selection fading in and out like so.

```
selection.enter().append("path").attr("opacity", 0).transition().attr("opacity", 1);
selection.exit().transition().attr("opacity", 0).remove();
```